# Jupyter Notebook RuntimeError: Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

trying to scrape amazon through jupyter notebook, my code runs fine through normal editors but fails in jupyter notebook for some reason :(

Python Version Installed : Python 3.9.1

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get("https://www.amazon.in/s?k=oneplus&page=1")
r.html.render(sleep=1)

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-9d8324f65180> in <module>
      1 s = HTMLSession()
      2 r = s.get("https://www.amazon.in/s?k=oneplus&page=1")
----> 3 r.html.render(sleep=1)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests_html.py in render(self, retries, script, wait, scrolldown, sleep, reload, timeout, keep_page)
    584         """
    585 
--> 586         self.browser = self.session.browser  # Automatically create a event loop and browser
    587         content = None
    588 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests_html.py in browser(self)
    727             self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    728             if self.loop.is_running():
--> 729                 raise RuntimeError("Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.")
    730             self._browser = self.loop.run_until_complete(super().browser)
    731         return self._browser

RuntimeError: Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.
```

Comment: `r.html.html` also works

Answer (score 1):

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

s = HTMLSession()
url="https://www.amazon.in/s?k=oneplus&page=1"
r = s.get(url)
ht= r.text
print(ht)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: hi it worked, but will it also render the javascript ??

Comment: the documentation is vague..but it supports the js unlike the requests module

Comment: hi i tried the r.html.render(), but unfortunately i get the same runtime error again :(

Comment: `r.html.html` or `r.text`

Comment: I feel like this should retrieve the JS pulled data "fabna054@uottawa.ca" in a URL like https://uniweb.uottawa.ca/members/5255/profile, but it doesn't. Is this the right tool, do others see that this script works, or am I seeing an anomaly on my test system and windows python setup?